# Regarding EC2+MySQL vs. RDS for Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I plan to move a site from a shared host to AWS. For that I plan to use a medium EC2 Ubuntu instance on which I will install wordpress.

The question I have is regarding my lack of understanding of the difference between installing MySQL into my EC2 instance and creating another RDS instance to manage the DB for Wordpress (apart from the cost of another instance just for the MySQL DB)

I do understand that RDS seems a more robust solution for big sites and lots of transactions, but for a WP site with 5000 visits a day what will be the adequate solution?

Thanks

Comment: With 5,000 visits a day, you might want to consider a micro or a small instance to start with.

Comment: If your traffic levels are that low you can install it all on a single instance. If you find the traffic levels increase significantly it would be a trivial task to then move the db to a new RDS instance. You may even want to consider a service like http://wpengine.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I will go with EC2 + MySQL and if traffic increase consider RDS. I read porting shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 5,000 visits a day, either one will be fine. The main benefit to RDS isn't power, but the fact that it's managed. Amazon handles version upgrades, backups, etc. for you, whereas with an EC2 instance you have to do that all yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so basically I can have the same "service" on the EC2 instance just that I have to do it myself?

Comment: Right. More work for you, but significantly cheaper for a small site.

Comment: Are there any tutorials for how to set up the scenario with a separate RDS instance? I'm having trouble getting mine working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153753/installing-wordpress-on-ec2-instance-with-the-database-on-an-rds-instance?noredirect=1#comment65652549_39153753

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your money on two instances, one should be more than enough for the wordpress + MySQL and should give you great results